# Avoid re-build of AWS Lambda Layer in CDK

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have a CDK stack that, among other infrastructure elements, deploys an AWS Lambda Layer (or actually a `lambda.LayerVersion`). I noticed that every time I update the stack a new version of the Layer is built, although its contents do not change. This leads to a whole bunch of layers that are inherently the same. Is there an easy way to avoid this behaviour and only create a new layer version when the contents actually change?

```js
const testLambdaLayer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, 'TestLambdaLayer', {
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('../test/lambda/layer/'),
  compatibleRuntimes: [lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8],
  layerVersionName: 'requests-layer',
})
```

Comment: Are you sure the contents actually don't change? CDK computes the hash of the directory contents and doesn't update if it's the same.

Comment: You are correct. I was building the layer and cdk stack via an automated CodeBuild pipeline. To avoid making my repository too large I only downloaded the python packages during the pipeline which apparently leads to cdk thinking the contents of the layer changed.